# JAXB reusing unmarshalled object

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

i am new to JAXB.

Currently what I have achieved are:

1) generated classes in eclipse with a .xsd file (predefined by external party)

2) tried marshalling/unmarshalling from sample xml that is complied to the .xsd

What I would like to find out is that:

After unmarshalled, let says the object unmarshalled is "STUDENT", I would like to pass this object to initialize another class which is extended from "STUDENT".

For example (STUDENT),

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "age"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "STUDENT")
public class STUDENT {
//.... sample student class
}
```

For example (STUDENTEXTENDED),

```
public class STUDENTEXTENDED extends STUDENT {
//.... sample extended class (I fake this out. May not make sense)
private STUDENT student;
private String homeAddress:
}
```

if the extended class is called "STUDENTEXTENDED", and **I would like to marshall this STUDENTEXTENDED to xml file**, how should I declare my root element as there is already a @XmlRootElement in STUDENT class? Can this be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple root element in JAXB.

Here's an example :

**Response.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class Response {
...
}
```

**ErrorResponse.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "error")
public class ErrorResponse extends Response {
...
}
```